# SFTP Connection suddenly not working

Tags: ssh, sftp

we have an sftp connection that suddenly stopped working and is throwing "Connection closed by remote host". It hangs for a long time on **sending packet type 50** line after which it succeeds on **Authentication (none)** and then immediately aborts with **Connection closed by remote host**

I searched some questions here with the same error but they all have the ssh_exchange tag before them which we don't

I've attached the verbose log if it helps.

```
C:\Users\rpaadm>sftp -vvv -i "C:\Users\rpaadm\Box Sync\RPA-PROD-Key\Private_Key\SFTP\id_rsa" <userid>@<hostname>
OpenSSH_7.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "<hostname>" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to <hostname> [<ip>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\rpaadm\\Box Sync\\RPA-PROD-Key\\Private_Key\\SFTP\\id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\rpaadm\\Box Sync\\RPA-PROD-Key\\Private_Key\\SFTP\\id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to <hostname>:22 as '<userid>'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/rpaadm/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/rpaadm/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from <hostname>
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:mhyTB66oPwGzJyNcd9ZdKbG4H5NV9aaZwv61J6ecsYA
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/rpaadm/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/rpaadm/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from <hostname>
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/rpaadm/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/rpaadm/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from <ip>
debug1: Host '<hostname>' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/rpaadm/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\rpaadm\\Box Sync\\RPA-PROD-Key\\Private_Key\\SFTP\\id_rsa (0x0), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug1: Authentication succeeded (none).
Authenticated to <hostname> ([<ip>]:22).
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t3 r-1 i0/0 o0/0 fd 4/5 cc -1)

debug3: fd 0 is not O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
Connection to <hostname> closed by remote host.
Transferred: sent 1660, received 1836 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 36274.7, received 40120.6
debug1: Exit status -1
Connection closed
```

I think the main issue is that it succeeds on none instead of returning the banner and the other authentication methods. Logging in without a key/ with incorrect key returns the same error. We don't even get a password prompt.

I'm trying to request the sshd logs but no one from my contacts on the sftp server team seems to know how to locate i. It might take a while for me to get anything from their end.

Remote server is z/OS btw

EDIT:  Finally able to secure some info from server end. the actual error is ***FOTS1450 Timeout before authentication*** but server admin is unable to determine why. A quick google of the error code says that this might be related to ***LoginGraceTime*** parameter which makes me confused as we were able to login before

Comment: Check the logs on the server.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've already requested for it since yesterday. The guys at the other end doesnt seem to know who can do it or how to do it so I'm kinda stuck. Is there no way for me to determine the issue from client end?

Comment: No, because from the client end your connection is successful.

Comment: @MichaelHampton will pester them to check on it. From our log, is the authentication succeeding on none ok? We were trying to authenticate with a private key in this logfile